# Removed parameters with htaccess but still have both clean and parameter urls

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a url in menu like this :

*http://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=contact_us*

and i'm using the following in .htaccess to turn it into a 'clean' url:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?main_page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

even though this works, as in I can get to the contact page no problem using *http://www.example.com/contact_us* it doesn't actually alter the original link to be like that.

So now I am thinking I need to either alter the link in the php menu to use the clean url or use a better htaccess rewrite rule that does it automatically. I would prefer the latter, any ideas?

Comment: U need to alter the links yourself. rewriting does not do this :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply DarkBee but just fyi it can be done ;) Check the accepted answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this new rule to do this redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?main_page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?main_page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much anubhava I was just about to give up when I looked at DarkBee's comment... it works perfectly

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. But it is always better to fix all HTML links eventually.

Comment: Ok i will do that as well, I've hardcoded one of the links into my menu and your solution still works so that is great. Thanks again